# ruby http request freeze with SSL

Tags: ruby, http

I'm trying to download images with ruby and found interesting issue

Its part of my  code for downloading an image (HTTP request only):

```
HTTParty.get(url)
```

or with

```
Net::HTTP.new(URI.parse(url))
```

and when I'm trying to download an image from Nike

```
url = 'https://c.static-nike.com/a/images/t_PDP_1728_v1/f_auto,b_rgb:f5f5f5/bfau7aauvleh5puvuiqa/zoom-pegasus-turbo-mens-running-shoe-Z163c3.jpg'
```

it works well

but for some reasons, it freezes when I'm opening Adidas:

```
url = 'https://www.adidas.com.sg/dis/dw/image/v2/bcbs_prd/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-adidas-products/default/dw0eb054ad/zoom/G27805_01_standard.jpg'
```

I have suck logs

```
    SSL established
<- "GET /dis/dw/image/v2/bcbs_prd/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-adidas-products/default/dw0eb054ad/zoom/G27805_01_standard.jpg HTTP/1.1\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0\r\nConnection: close\r\nHost: www.adidas.com.sg\r\n\r\n"
```

tried to switch off SSL validation by

```
 verify: false,
```

but it doesn't solve my pain ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

However, it works well with `curl -O` for both URLs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is filtering being done on the server side for the Adidas URL, likely to prevent automated scraping. At a minimum you must specify additional headers to successfully make a connection.

The following example successfully returns a response from the Adidas URL:

```
url = 'https://www.adidas.com.sg/dis/dw/image/v2/bcbs_prd/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-adidas-products/default/dw0eb054ad/zoom/G27805_01_standard.jpg'

headers = {
  'Accept' => 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
  'Accept-Encoding' => 'br, gzip, deflate',
  'Accept-Language' => 'en-us'
}

response = HTTParty.get(url, headers: headers)
=> #<HTTParty::Response:0x7fcb02856298 parsed_response="\xFF\xD8\xFF\xE0\x00\x10JFIF ...
```

The three headers listed are the only headers required to get a response, but all three headers are required.

You can see from the returned response that it is returning [a JPEG](https://boonedocks.net/blog/2008/03/10/Determining-Image-File-Types-in-Ruby.html), so this example should work as requested.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that they block requests when some specific headers are missing, so you might want to set some of them:

```
 HTTParty.get(url, { headers: {
                       "User-Agent" => "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) FxiOS/7.0.4 Mobile/16B91 Safari/605.1.15",
                       "Accept-Language" => "en-US,en;q=0.9,bg;q=0.8",
                       "Accept-Encoding" => "gzip, deflate, br"
                     }
                   })
```